# Time complexity of Trie autocompletion (multiple variables in time complexity)

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, trees

I am trying to understand what the time complexity for an autocomplete function for a Trie-based dictionary would be. Every node contains a letter and whether it is the last letter of a word, and if so, how frequently it shows up in the english language.

From my understanding, if we have a Trie (prefix tree), and we search for the node representing the last letter of the prefix, this operation would take **O(k)** time, where k is the amount of letters in the prefix being searched.

In order to get all the words starting with the prefix, we then have to traverse down all child nodes using BFS/DFS which would be about **O(n)**? (correct me if I'm wrong).

Finally when we have a list of all words that start with the prefix, we have to sort them based on their frequency (so we suggest the most frequently appearing words first), this would take **O(n log n) **in the worst case.

Does this mean that the total time complexity is **O(k + n + n log n) = O(k + n log n)** (a time complexity with two variables, k and n)?

From this the k seems almost negligible, as this is only the amount of letters in the prefix, compared to n log n (which could be millions if the dictionary used is huge). But would I still need to write out this **O(k)** factor or is it ok to just leave it as **O(n log n)**?

[image]

I have tried to analyse the time complexity above, but not sure if I need to include the k variable in the time complexity.

Comment: Why do you care about what the theoretical worst-case running time is, if this is something you are going to use in practice?  Why do you assume that autocomplete needs to return all words that start with the prefix?  No autocomplete function I've ever seen does that.  What's the context where you encountered this task?  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @D.W. I'm not using this in practice but am currently learning about calculating the time complexity of various algorithms involving multiple variables. I am mainly wondering if I would I have to include O(k) in the theoretical time complexity (O(k + n log n)? Thanks for taking the time to read this.